# Android Emulator freezes and I do not get html code for the website

Tags: java, android, web-scraping

I am just creating a simple android app which logs the HTML code of a particular website. In the onCreate method, a string is passed which is the URL we want the HTML code of. Whenever i am running the app, I do not get the HTML code in the log and also the emulator freezes. It only works perfectly  for a specific link which is "https://www.zappycode.com/" . If any other link is passed, I will get the issues.
The code:

```
package com.example.guesswho;
 
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
 
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
 
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
 
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 
    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void, String>{
 
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String result=null;
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection= null;
            try{
                url= new URL(urls[0]);
                urlConnection= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream in= urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader= new InputStreamReader(in);
                int data= reader.read();
                while(data != -1){
                    char current= (char) data;
                    result+= current;
                    data= reader.read();
                }
                return result;
 
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "failed";
            }
 
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        DownloadTask task= new DownloadTask();
        String result= null;
        try{
            result= task.execute("https://www.imdb.com/list/ls052283250/").get(); //DOES NOT WORK 
            //result= task.execute("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICC_Player_Rankings").get();//DOES NOT WORK 
 
            //result= task.execute("https://www.zappycode.com/").get(); //THIS WORKS PERFECTLY
 
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("Result", result);
 
    }
}
```

Log when the imbd or Wikipedia link is passed.
[image: Clcik here to see the image of the Log when the imbd or Wikipedia link is passed]

Emulator when imbd or Wikipedia is passed: (home , switch app, and back buttons do not work and  the helloWorld textView is not visible)
[image: click to see the image of emulator]

Why is this happening and how can I solve it. Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your AndroidManifest.xml file under application tag.

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```